# Problem with adding custom php code in OpenCart using Jourlan 3 theme

Tags: php, twig, opencart

I am new to open cart but I am good in core PHP. Actually I am creating a flash sales on the website. Admin side I have done and everything working good but for front end I have php code I want to know if there is any way so I can put it on the website after header, or is there any way to display custom php file as a module on the website layout ? I just want to embed that php code on the website and if there can be any option to turn it on and off from the admin panel that would be great. I was done this using advanced grid module on the other template of opencart but on the new installed template (journal 3) there is no way to use advanced grid. if there please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding a dynamic block to the site in journal 3 theme and it works great for me. Thank you so much for your help by the way.

Answer (score 0):

**Journal 3** theme - is a detail, that changes everything. As you mentioned, there is no way to use advanced grid.

Journal 3 has it's own grid system. In admin panel go to *Journal - Layout*. You will see layouts. Click on one of them. There you have to sort it out a bit. In some point you will find out, how to choose a module, by clicking on the **Add** button inside of the **Row**. In popup window you will see on the left side the list of Journal modules. Scroll till the end of the list, and the last item will be **Opencart**. Clicking on it you will see a list of standard opencart modules (including yours), set is, save. That's how you can add your custom module to Journal 3.

But if you are a developer - I advice you not to use Journal 3. This is a theme for regular users, who can install and manage it without any programming knowledge. For a developer it is nightmare to edit Journal 3 core, every forum a read about in - was telling no to do than. If you want to edit core - use default template or some simple for developers one.

**UPDATED**

1. Advanced module grid will not work properly inside or the Journal 3 grid.
2. More about correct Dynamic Blocks construction you can read here.  https://docs.journal-theme.com/docs/modules/blocks/#dynamic-blocks
3. You can make a cope of a module, for example HTML, and rewrite it, using your code. In this case you will consider all requirements of OpenCart MVC.

Without seen a controller it's all i can tell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but in my case there is no Opencart button in list of the modules in the popup. Any idea how can I get it there ? Please have a loop at screenshot https://ibb.co/p1LmnY5

Comment: Before that you should setting and enable module in Extensions - Extensions - Modules. Is it done? Only after that lis list will appear.

Comment: I directly access opencart by changing the url in browser like #/module_layout/opencart and now I can see opencart modules but I can not see advanced grid module which I want to use.

Comment: Try to enable som standard OC module and look for it in Jourlan layout settings. For experiment. And tell me journal concert version

Comment: Ok, i see. At some reason your module is not on the list. Maybe your module doesn’t have lang files in admin? At some reason Journal can’t see it

Comment: Its Journal 3.0.44 If you please help me in blocks I can fix this issue. Actually I want to use dynamic block and dynamic controller file I have php code which is working good. But the problem if when I include that dynamic block on the layout it's showing on the block content and rest of all not showing. Please check screenshot: https://ibb.co/hK4pRZB

Comment: in the flash_sale.php I have like echo '123' https://ibb.co/GF8sKbR

Comment: I added that block on the sitemap page for testing so instead of showing block content after sitemap content it's only showing block content https://ibb.co/Y7VwVQw

Comment: Updated an answer a little, maybe it will help